# How can I calculate how many times a value is present excluding another value?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a column for which I need to count how many times the value "Good" is present without calculating the "Neutral" Value?

This is the sample table:

| Col1 |
| --- |
| Bad |
| Neutral |
| Good |
| Bad |
| Neutral |
| Okay |

Here is what I have so far but I kept

```
Measure = CALCULATE(Col1],Table[Col1] = "Good",ALLEXCEPT(Table,Table[Col1]="Neutral" ))
```

but I end up getting this error:

> A single value for column 'Intune Owner Email' in table 'users' cannot be determined. This can happen when a measure formula refers to a column that contains many values without specifying an aggregation such as min, max, count, or sum to get a single result.

How can I work around this?

Comment: Why don't you just use the `count` function to count the number of "Good" directly? Why do you need to deliberately exclude "Neutral"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why whould you need to except `Col1 = Neutral` for this?

This measure counts the number of rows where `Col1 = "Good"`:

```
# Good := 
CALCULATE ( 
    COUNT ( 'Table'[Col1] ) ,
    'Table'[Col1] = "Good" 
)
```

If you are after a different type of filtering semantics, you can try also invoking `KEEPFILTERS`:

```
# Good Variant = 
CALCULATE ( 
    COUNT ( 'Table'[Col1] ) ,
    KEEPFILTERS ( 'Table'[Col1] = "Good" ) 
)
```

The difference between the semantics can be shown here:

[image]